# Remove inaccessible vertical checkbox margin

Tags: html, css, checkbox, margin

I am trying to create a grid of checkboxes.
Therefore I am trying to remove all whitespaces between them, but there seem to be some vertical margins or line heights in the background that I cannot control:

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div><input type="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></div>
<div><input type="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></div>
<div><input type="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></div>
```

But I know it has to be possible, since, with `display: block`, the vertical margin is gone.

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div><input type="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></div>
<div><input type="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></div>
<div><input type="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></div>
```

well, I need them inline though.

Where is the space coming from and how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: row` to it, therefore they will be inline without vertical spacing.

Comment: `display: flex` for the divs solved it, `flex-direction: row` is default behaviour. Do you know why that works and what is happening internally?

Comment: You can read more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5078297

Comment: almost, the solution is the same, but the problem and explanation are different (horizontal vs vertical). The user is havin problems with horizontal spaces, that can be solved by removing the new lines between the elements. This explains where it is coming from, but it seems not to be the same root cause here. The font-size trick, also seems to work though... so it is highly related but not the same somehow.

Comment: anyway, inline block styling feels kind of old, useless and obtrusive when you have much better options like flexbox or grid, I would definitely go for them.

Comment: That sounds like a good argument, thanks for your help and effort!